# Hom and Tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\gamma:V\to W\otimes L$, $\operatorname{rank}(L)=1$, be a map. Using $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W\otimes L)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)\otimes L$ we can get $\gamma':V\to W$. If $\gamma'$ not be an isomorphism can we conclude that $\gamma$ also can't be an isomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. $\gamma  \cong \gamma'$ in $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathsf{Vect}_K)$ after choosing an isomorphism $L \cong K$.